# Группировка (статистика) по Стерджессу

Tags: python, pandas, статистика, анализ-данных

Хочу сделать группировку Стерджесса на `Python`. Никто не знает, где можно про это почитать? Так и не поняла, как сделать группировку `data frame` по определённому интервалу (гуглила, есть только про группы).

Теперь как-то надо задать чтобы столбец `Fixed_assets_value` сгруппировал
`xmin+ i`, потом `xmin+ i * 2` и так до `xmin+ i*n`.
и вывел это сначала в виде дата фрейма (при этом в каждой группе посчитав общую сумму значений и добавил колонки).
Прикладываю скрины, как я пыталась решить эту задачу.

**P.S.** [Вот](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/eToW/DsJGL1HHo) исходные данные. Помогите кто может.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('zad_p.csv', delimiter=';')
df = df.rename(columns={'fixed assets value': 'Fixed_assets_value', 'gross output  at constant prices': 'Gross_output_at_constant_prices', 'average on establishment number of workers' : 'Average_on_establishment_number_of_workers', 'Average daily processing of beets' : 'Average_daily_processing_of_beets'})
import math
quantity = len(df)
y = math.log10(quantity)
n = 1 + (3.322*y) 
print(n)
n = math.ceil(n)
print (n)
xmax = df['Fixed_assets_value'].max()
xmin = df['Fixed_assets_value'].min()
i = ((xmax - xmin)/ n)
print (xmin, xmax, math.ceil(i))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: там в коде две строки с ```df2``` "висят в воздухе"... это что?

Comment: Спасибо. исправила...но проблема не решенной задачи осталась...вопрос про группировку (

Comment: Из вопроса не очень понятно как именно вы хотите группировать данные и что вы хотите получить в результате. Поэтому я попросил привести в вопросе небольшой пример и результат, который вы ожидаете получить. Все детали, относящиеся к вопросу, должны быть в теле вопроса в виде текста, а не в виде скриншотов.

Comment: @Юлия, [что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: я изучаю спасибо. можно пока не удалять?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
i = np.ceil(((xmax - xmin)/ n))
bins = np.arange(xmin, xmax+i, i)
labels = np.arange(1, len(bins))

df["group_id"] = pd.cut(df["Fixed_assets_value"], bins=bins, 
                        labels=labels, right=False)
```

результат:

```
In [181]: df
Out[181]:
     №  Fixed_assets_value  Gross_output_at_constant_prices  Average_on_establishment_number_of_workers  Average_daily_processing_of_beets group_id
0    1                 500                              535                                         420                               12.2        2
1    2                 693                              688                                         550                               13.2        3
2    3                 690                              705                                         570                               13.7        3
3    4                1010                              725                                         883                               18.0        5
4    5                 810                              526                                         433                               10.7        4
5    6                1112                             1110                                         839                               12.0        6
6    7                 488                              353                                         933                               14.2        2
7    8                 735                              543                                         526                               12.1        3
8    9                1007                              768                                         693                               20.8        5
9   10                 788                              823                                         684                               11.0        4
10  11                 703                              408                                        1291                               20.7        3
11  12                 485                             1047                                         553                               18.5        2
12  13                 435                              610                                         496                               17.4        1
13  14                 343                              531                                         367                               12.4        1
14  15                 806                              740                                         706                               21.3        4
15  16                 611                              708                                         555                               18.4        2
16  17                 979                              634                                         623                               22.1        5
17  18                 385                              152                                         371                               10.7        1
18  19                1083                             1143                                         977                               45.3        6
19  20                 670                              410                                         738                               16.9        3
20  21                 663                             1337                                         992                               17.7        3
21  22                 647                              634                                         495                               20.0        3
22  23                 608                              362                                         456                               13.9        2
23  24                 811                              492                                         789                               24.5        4
24  25                 947                              904                                         628                               23.1        5
25  26                1186                              536                                         653                               18.2        6
26  27                 469                              627                                         456                                9.0        1
27  28                 849                             1709                                        1023                               27.3        4
28  29                 756                             1164                                         581                               17.7        3
29  30                 643                             1263                                         552                               19.7        3
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы все делаете почти правильно, только чуть чуть не дотянули до конца.
Ниже работающий пример кода. По признаку "А" делим на интервалы по правилу Стерджесса, по признаку "B" - суммируем внутри группы. Надеюсь применить это к вашему коду  сумеете самостоятельно.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': a,'B':b})
n=math.ceil(3.322*math.log10(len(a))+1 )
a_groups = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=n)
df.groupby(a_groups)['B'].sum()
```